# Using a select case with oracle and always return all conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Problem:

I need to aggregate the price on a table by certain values so i do

```
select t.r as score_range, count(*) as number_of_occurences
from (
  select case  
    when publicsellingprice between 0 and 5000 then ' 0-5k'
    when publicsellingprice between 5000 and 10000 then '5-10k'
    when publicsellingprice between 10000 and 20000 then '10-20k'
    when publicsellingprice between 20000 and 400000 then '20-40k'
    when publicsellingprice between 40000 and 80000 then '40-80k'   
    else '80-999K' end as r
  from product) t
group by t.r
order by 1
```

This works no problem. If i test this with values only from 5-k it displays only that row;
what i want is to have always the full 5 rows of data and when there is no values for the given conditions i want 0 or null or something else. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a left outer join. The simplest way (IMO) is to use subquery factoring, AKA a common table expression, to provice the range information, and then left join that to your product table:

```
with ranges as (
  select 0 as min_price, 5000 as max_price, ' 0-5k' as score_range from dual
  union all select 5000, 10000, '5-10k' from dual
  union all select 10000, 20000, '10-20k' from dual
  union all select 20000, 40000, '20-40k' from dual
  union all select 40000, 80000, '40-80k' from dual
  union all select 80000, 999000, '80-999k' from dual
)
select r.score_range, count(publicsellingprice) as number_of_occurences
from ranges r
left join product p on p.publicsellingprice between r.min_price and r.max_price
group by r.score_range, r.min_price
order by r.min_price;
```

However, using `between` might not give you the results you want; something exactly on a boundary, e.g. where the `publicsellingprice` is `5000`, will be counted in two buckets. You could either adjust the min/max price in the CTE to give an upper range (e.g. `4999.99`), or comare them differently:

```
with ranges as (
  select 0 as min_price, 5000 as max_price, ' 0-5k' as score_range from dual
  union all select 5000, 10000, '5-10k' from dual
  union all select 10000, 20000, '10-20k' from dual
  union all select 20000, 40000, '20-40k' from dual
  union all select 40000, 80000, '40-80k' from dual
  union all select 80000, 999000, '80-999k' from dual
)
select r.score_range, count(publicsellingprice) as number_of_occurences
from ranges r
left join product p on p.publicsellingprice >= r.min_price
  and p.publicsellingprice < r.max_price
group by r.score_range, r.min_price
order by r.min_price;
```

In both cases I've included the `min_price` in the `group by` so you can order by that too; otherwise you're ordering by the string comparision rules, which would put your 5k bracket between 40k and 80k.

Comment: this works, thanks. Now, a somewhat side-question... some folks here say that union all isnt the best performant of query constructs, is that true?

Comment: @sergio - it depends what you're doing, sometimes it's appropriate, but like anything else it can be abused. Probably would need to see examples, but then it might make a separate question. `union all` is better than `union` unless you explicitly need to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, just add some fictious rows to sum with real data:

```
select res.score_range, sum(res.number_of_occurences) number_of_occurences FROM
(select ' 0-5k' score_range, 0 number_of_occurences from dual
union
select '5-10k' score_range, 0 number_of_occurences from dual
union
select '10-20k' score_range, 0 number_of_occurences from dual
union
select '20-40k' score_range, 0 number_of_occurences from dual
union
select '40-80k' score_range, 0 number_of_occurences from dual
union
select t.r as score_range, count(*) as number_of_occurences
from (
  select case  
    when publicsellingprice between 0 and 5000 then ' 0-5k'
    when publicsellingprice between 5000 and 10000 then '5-10k'
    when publicsellingprice between 10000 and 20000 then '10-20k'
    when publicsellingprice between 20000 and 400000 then '20-40k'
    when publicsellingprice between 40000 and 80000 then '40-80k'   
    else '80-999K' end as r
  from product) t
group by t.r
order by 1) res
group by res.score_range
```